# Spring - Dynamically add and remove scheduled task

Tags: java, spring, spring-scheduled

I am working on `spring` based server application. Basically it will poll scores of various sporting events in very short interval and save in db. For polling there will be many(can be around 100) calls to different apis concurrently at regular interval for example some api call will have 3 seconds interval some have 5 seconds etc., server will keep polling for latest data at frequent interval.

These calls will be added and removed dynamically. I have little experience in using spring. I think I have to use some scheduler. Can anyone point in right direction what approach or which scheduler is best in this scenario.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In essence you want to inject an instance of a scheduling task executor

```
@Configuration
public class MyApplicationConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler() {
        ThreadPoolTaskScheduler tpts = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
        // maybe configure it a little?
        return tpts;
    }

    @Bean
    public MyService myService() {
        return new MyService();
    }
}

class MyService {
    @Autowired
    private ThreadPoolTaskScheduler tpts;

    public void doSomething() {
        Runnable task = ...
        tpts.scheduleWithFixedDelay(task, 1000);
    }
}
```

You can see a [reasonable guide here](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-task-scheduler), or the [SchedulingTaskExecutor Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/SchedulingTaskExecutor.html) and the [Spring Task Execution and Scheduling Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#scheduling)

Comment: thanks for reply. I will look into it. Do you know when we use Quartz scheduler?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@Scheduled` Spring Annotation for this. Refer this [link](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring/spring-core/4-ways-to-schedule-tasks-in-spring-3-scheduled-example/) for examples.

Comment: thanks for reply, but I think it is not dynamic. I cannot add or remove task at runtime.